# What is the URL to open the Outlook Web Client in the calendar page?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I can setup a bookmark to open up the Outlook Web Client for Exchange Server 2013, but it always opens in the email page. I want a URL that opens the calendar. Is there an easy way to do this without digging into the javascript?

Answer (score 5):

It's just as simple as this:

```
https://yourexchangeserveraddr/owa?cmd=contents&module=calendar
```

Actually you can open any module this way. Also works with Exchange 2010.

Comment: That kind of works for me. Our implementation requires this `https://yourexchangeserveraddr/owa/?cmd=contents&module=calendar`. Note the extra slash after `owa`. Is there a web page that shows where this link comes from?

Comment: The common syntax is described here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: The problem with these links is when it auto logs out the login page goes to mail, not to calendar.  I know it's only a few clicks to get back, but it's very annoying to do every day.